# Undo a merge that has been pushed

Tags: git, merge, reset, revert

OK, I have made a bit of a mess. Apparently, on my machine at home, the develop branch was not updated. I made a commit and pushed. The result was that the actual origin/develop branch has been merged into my local develop branch - which for some reason were considered as different branches!

For one thing, I really don't understand how this happened and second of all, can I undo this?

To illustrate it, the network looks something like this now:

```
 local-develop ---------------------------------- C*--- M -
origin/develop --- C --- C --- C --- C --- C --------- /
```

What I really wanted was that the C* would be committed to the origin/develop instead of merging the branches.

As I said, this has been pushed already. Is there a way to delete the changes and commit it the way I wanted?

For example I do:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

I am not sure if this undoes the merge and I have two different develops, and then the merge deleted etc...?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Merges don't happen on push, they happen on `git merge` (well, and `pull` but that's really just fetch + merge, hence, merge happening on merge).

It seems more likely that you did something like this:

```
<get copy from origin/develop>
<wait around for remote's origin/develop to acquire new commits>
git checkout develop      # get onto (local) develop branch
<edit>
git commit -m message     # create some new commit(s)
git push origin develop   # attempt to push -- but this fails!
git pull
```

It's that last step that creates the merge commit (`M` above), because `pull` means `fetch` (get all those new commits that are now in `origin/develop`), then `merge` (take your local `develop` and merge your commit with those new ones just fetched).

If you haven't `git push`ed this *new* result, then the remote repo doesn't have *either* of your local commits, the ones you've labeled `C*` and `M`.  In this case, you're in good shape!  (You can check by running `git fetch` again to make sure your local repo's `origin/develop` matches the one in the remote, then doing `git log origin/develop` to see what's in it.)

It may help to remember that there are two completely separate git repos here: yours, with your stuff; and the one you're calling `origin` here.  (Let's call that machine `X`.)  If you were to log on to `X`, it has its own separate commit history and branch names and so on.  Over there, you would change directory to the repo, run `git log -1 develop`, and see what's at the tip of that branch.

Now if you log off of `X` and are back on your own machine, you can run `git log -1 origin/develop`.  If that's the same as what you saw on `X`, then `get fetch` has nothing to update, because what `git fetch` does is, in effect (but more efficiently), log on to `X` and look at what's in `develop` there.  Anything that `X` has that you don't have in `origin/develop`, `fetch` brings over and adds to `origin/develop`.  Now you're in sync with `X`.  `X` doesn't have your stuff, but you have theirs.

If you then take the extra step of doing a `merge` (including the one implied by `pull`), git will, if it has to, make a merge commit ... but all this is in *your* repo, at the tip of the branch (still `develop` in this case).  Unless and until you push this merge commit to `X` (or someone on `X` pulls your commits from you but let's ignore that for now :-) ), `X` won't have it.

Anyway, as long as the remote (`X` here) does not have your merge commit, you're golden.  Since *they* don't have it, nobody else does either.  You can do a `rebase` of your `develop` branch to put your commit (`C*`) on top of `origin/develop`.  That will get rid of the merge commit (`M`), and then you can push a simple fast-forward to `origin/develop`.

If `X` *does* have your merge commit—i.e., if you pushed after you `pull`ed and got that merge—then you're stuck (to some extent) because presumably other people have access to `X` and are now using your merge commit.  It's possible to roll back the repo on `X`, similar to the way you can do this in your own repo with `git reset` and `git rebase` and so on, but it's generally a bad idea.

---

Now, suppose you *have* in fact pushed to the other repo (on machine `X`), but you're absolutely sure nobody else has seen your changes yet, and you're definitely going to reset them, rather than reverting them (reverting amounts to "fessing up" and leaving the screwup-record behind, which lets everyone else recover from it easily, but also lets them see your error :-) ).<sup>1</sup>

Here's the trick: you first need to get machine X's repo to say that "tip of branch `devel` is commit C7", where C7 is in your very own diagram from earlier, just re-numbered so that I can name each commit differently:

```
--------------------------- C*--- M
--- C4 --- C5 --- C6 --- C7 ---- /
```

So, how can you do that?  Well, one way is to log in on `X`,<sup>2</sup> `cd` into the repo (even if it's `--bare`), and use `git update-ref` there.  Let's say the SHA1 for C7 is actually `50db850` (as shown by "git log").  Then you could do this:

```
localhost$ ssh X
X$ cd /path/to/repo.git
X$ git update-ref refs/heads/develop 50db850
```

But if you can't log in to `X`, or even just don't want to, you can do the same with `git push -f`.<sup>3</sup>  (This has other advantages: in particular, your git repo will know that `origin/develop` has been rewound, once the `push -f` completes successfully.)  Just make a local branch-tip pointing to the right commit:<sup>4</sup>

```
localhost$ git branch resetter 50db850
localhost$ git log resetter         # make sure it looks right
...
localhost$ git push -f origin resetter:develop
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://[redacted]
 + 21011c9...50db850 resetter -> develop (forced update)
localhost$ git branch -d resetter   # we don't need it anymore
```

Once you have done this, machine X is back in the state you wanted it, and you can proceed as if you never pushed the merge you didn't like.

Note that when you do the `push -f`, if anyone else has made new commits on top of `M`, those will *also* become invisible (technically they're still in there, along with your merge commit, but they are "lost" in the `lost+found` sense of `git fsck --lost-found`, and after a few months they'll really go away forever).<sup>5</sup>

Again and **very important**: this kind of "rollback of shared repo" is a big pain for other users of that shared repo, so be really sure it's OK before you do it.

---

<sup>1</sup>This sort of trivial merge doesn't even need reverting.  There's nothing fundamentally wrong with leaving the merge in there.  If you're dealing with a more serious mistaken merge, though, there's one other disadvantage to reverting a merge, besides the record of your "oops": it makes "redoing" the changes later a bit harder, in that a later "merge on purpose" will see the earlier merge and think: OK, I don't need to re-merge *those* changes.  You then have to "revert the revert" instead.

I think the right take-away lesson here is: **look (`git log`) before you push** to make sure that what you are about to push is what you intend to push.

<sup>2</sup>Or, easier and simpler: `git ls-remote`.  This uses the fetch protocol code to see what the remote has.  But it hides the theme I'm going for here, which is: the remote is a repo just like yours!

<sup>3</sup>The upcoming git version 2 releases have new "safety features" that will be useable with `git push -f`.  But they're not out yet, so that doesn't help you.  I'll re-edit this later when they are, to note them.  Until then, be *really* careful here: you're racing against anyone else trying to push new stuff to the shared repository, at this point.

<sup>4</sup>You can even do this by raw SHA-1 ID.  The branch name is easier to type correctly several times in a row though.

<sup>5</sup>The retaining and expiration is via git's "reflogs".  The shared server may not be logging all ref updates; if not, only private repos that already had the new commits will retain them.  The shortest default expiration is 30 days, i.e., about one month, for commits no longer reachable from the branch tip.  But note, it's a no-fun, crazy scramble to make everyone search through their repositories for "lost" commits after force-pushes "lose work" off a shared repository.

Comment: wow, thanks a lot for this extensive answer. Unluckily I have pushed it to X. Since I am sure that nobody else has made the a new fetch, I was wondering if I can undo these changes.

One thing I really am not clear about: If I make a reset two steps back, am I left with one of the branches or with both?

Comment: OK, well, after pushing, if you're *really sure* :-) ... what you want to do is get X's idea of the tip of branch `devel` to rewind a bit.  Let me edit the answer...

Comment: Oh, and: if you `git reset HEAD~2` to "move two steps back", this really amounts to telling git: "set the tip of the branch that I'm on now"—presumably this would be your `develop`—"to the commit-ID you get by looking up HEAD~2".  If you want to see what commit that is, `git show HEAD~2` first.  If you're at commit `M` from your diagram above, `HEAD~2` is `M~2` which backs up over both `M` and `C*`.  Probably not what you want.

Comment: Ok, super. Big lesson learnt today! Thank you so much. reset HEAD~2 would do exactly the opposite of I wanted :-), so the help above is very useful

Comment: @torek sir, you just saved my ass big time!

Comment: @torek your verbosity matches your generosity! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here the responses by Linus Torvals Here the responses by Linus Torvals http://opensource.apple.com/source/Git/Git-26/src/git-htmldocs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt