# How to undo a merge on a branch where there have been subsequent commits?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rewrite-history

Let's say I have a `develop` branch where multiple people branch off of to work on either bugfixes or features.

Let's say now I have a branch called `featureA` that I worked on while some other person worked on `featureB` and someone else on `bugfixA`.

I accidentally merged my `featureA` branch into `develop`. `featureB` and `bugfixA` are also merged into `develop` but do not need to be unmerged.

Now we carved a branch off of develop with all those merges and called it `releaseA`. So now I need to unmerge my `featureA` from `releaseA`and put a PR for that.

How do I go about this?

Here's what I'm thinking:

1. `git log` which will show the commit id for the `featureA` merge
2. `git reset --merge <commit id for featureA`
3. `git commit 'merge revert'`
4. `git push` to `releaseA`

Now I haven't tried this because I'm unsure what happens to the other merges if I revert my commit, because `featureB` and `bugfixA` merges happened in `develop` after my merge and don't need to be removed from the `releaseA`. Only `featureA` needs to be removed from `releaseA` and I need to submit another PR for that unmerge.

Will that affect the other merges/commits?

Is this the right track or am I missing something?

Example of `git log --oneline --graph`

```
*   f092f2f0f (HEAD -> release/releaseA, origin/release/releaseA, origin/develop, origin/HEAD, develop) Merge branch 'feature/featureB' into 'develop'
|\  
| * f023f02f9 (origin/feature/featureB) commit mesage feat A
* |   f2902f921 Merge branch 'feature/featureA' into 'develop'
|\ \  
| * | 3e2011910 (origin/feature/featureA, feature/featureA) feat: commit feat B
* | |   0131f1921 Merge branch 'bugfix/bugfixA' into 'develop'
|\ \ \  
| |/ /  
|/| |   
| * | f29190198 some commit message
|/ /  
* |   013e9112f Merge branch 'bugfix/bugfixB' into 'develop'
|\ \  
| * | 37f78f300 another rcommit message
* | |   29aef3119 Merge branch 'bugfix/featureC' into 'develop'
|\ \ \  
| |/ /  
|/| |   
| * | a819cd3d6 (origin/bugfix/featureC, bugfix/featureC) update: feat C commit msg
| * | 031119101 fix: some fix
| * | c1ec250d7 fix: some other fix
* | |   771ee7a10 Merge branch 'bugfix/bugfixC' into 'develop'
```

I think it's important to mention that I ran that command on releaseA branch. releaseA branch is basically carved off develop and I need to unmerge featureA from releaseA but keep it in develop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undo a Git merge that hasn't been pushed yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2389361/undo-a-git-merge-that-hasnt-been-pushed-yet)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I actually looked at that before posting my question. I did a push to develop, so I think it doesn't work for my case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Undo a merge that has been pushed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176352/undo-a-merge-that-has-been-pushed)

Comment: Quick question, how easy is it for you to merge the `featureB` and `bugfixA` branches to `develop` branch? Were there a lot of conflicts that were resolved while merging both those branches to `develop` branch?

Comment: @Salvino Both branches were merged into `develop` along with `featureA`. However, we made a `releaseA` branch from `develop` which will be released and I only need to unmerge `featureA` from there.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Not really. They look like different problems. I did a lot of research before posting the question, and I did look at that too

Comment: I got that part. I just wanted to know, if we reset the branch to a one commit before the merge, how difficult is it for you to re-merge the other to branches i.e `featureB` and `bugfixA`?

Comment: @Salvino oh that would be tough as i need to get other devs to pretty much redo a bunch of stuff. There's also more stuff than those 2 after my merge

Comment: It's really hard to help you without a lot more detail. Please update the question with the output of `git log --oneline --graph develop featureA featureB  bugfixA`.

Comment: @Inigo Updated the question

Comment: So, to confirm, you want develop to stay as it is shown in the graph, and you want releaseA to simply not include featureA? My answer below assumes this. I will update it based on your reply.

Comment: Note that nobody creates a branch from a *branch*. They create new branch names from specific *commits*. Since a branch name like `develop` is constantly moving from commit C123 to C456 to C789, person A will create branch A from commit C123. Person B will create branch B from commit C456. Person C will create branch C from commit C789. They all used "branch develop" to create their branches, but they all started from different *commits*.

Answer (score 2):

Since you created a new branch, `releaseA`, for which you want to [rewrite history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1491001/what-are-the-practical-consequences-of-rewriting-git-history), and you are not messing with the shared `develop` branch, this should be easy.

Simply use `git rebase -i` to rewrite the history for `releaseA`:

1. The following command will let you rewrite history starting from the parent of the commit you want to remove (`f2902f921`, the merge commit for `featureA`):

   ```sh
   git rebase -i --rebase-merges f2902f921^ releaseA
   ```

   The `--rebase-merges` switch will replay merge commits as merge
   commits instead of as simple linear commits. If you don't need this behavior, exclude this switch. See `git help rebase` for more info.
2. In the interactive rebase commit list, remove the line for the merge commit, `f2902f921`. Or replace the word `pick` with `skip`. Either way that commit will not be included when the rebase commit list is replayed.
3. Save and close the rebase commit list. `git rebase` will now replay the commits in the order given in this list. You will have to deal with any conflicts as commits are replayed.
4. Check the results. Once you are satisfied, force push the rewritten history for `releaseA`:

   ```sh
   git push -f releaseA
   ```

   > #### ⚠️ Warning
   >
   > Review the dangers of rewriting history per my link above.
   > That said, given what you want to achieve, there is no way around this.

`git rebase -i` is one of the most powerful and useful commands in git. Learn it!